# Condicional dentro de un Where en un select Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola amigos quería hacer una consulta.

Lo que pasa es que tengo dos tablas en Sql Server las cuales hago un inner join y hasta ahi esta bien.
Mi problema es que necesito que en la condición del Where me condicione que si Id_Cliente = 0 me arroje todos los id_Clientes que tengo de la tabla,(como que hiciera un select from sin condición)

y si el Id_cliente = otro valor solo me arroje ese cliente.

Existe alguna manera de realizar esto ??

lo estaba intentando con case y con or pero no me sale.

Les dejo mi  consulta

```
SELECT  i.entregatotal,
        i.Id_Cliente,
        i.atiempo,
        c.nombre 
FROM Intiempo i
INNER JOIN VClientes c ON c.id_cliente = i.id_cliente 
WHERE   i.Id_Cliente = CASE WHEN i.Id_Cliente = 0 
                                        THEN i.Id_Cliente   
                                        ELSE i.Id_Cliente = i.Id_Cliente
```

Comment: Para este tipo de preguntas es recomendable añadir un pequeño ejemplo de los datos de entrada en cada tabla y la salida esperada. He leído tu explicación y no logro imaginar con precisión la salida que esperas obtener.

Comment: El where no puede ser condicional, porque ya es el condicional ;). Este tipo de cosas muy raras, no deberia solucionarse asi. Podrias explicarnos como llamas a esa query? la solucion puede estar en otro lado. Los case en las clausulas where suelen traer problemas al tratar de optimizar la consulta

Comment: @jachguate quiere toda la tabla (si no selecciono un cliente) o solo el cliente seleccionado... yo no lo solucionaria asi en ninguno de los casos...

Comment: ¿El id de cliente lo recibirás cómo un parámetro?

Comment: si lo explico mejor, mi id_cliente es un parámetro que recibo   y quiero que en el where   si en ese parámetro me trae 0 que lance la consulta normal como un select from sin el where y si ese parametro tiene otro valor  es decir me pone 1 que ahi si me traiga solo el  id_cliente que necesito .

Comment: Estas confundiendo tu variable/parametro con el nombre de la columna en tu condicion where, echa un vistazo a mi respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta es una lógica que yo hago en mis buscadores.

Nota: Presumo que usas SQL Server y consultas con parametros. Puedes adaptarla a tu lógica substituyendo la condición `is null` por `= 0`

```
where 
    (@parametro1 is null or columna1 = @parametro1)
    and
    (@parametro2 is null or columna2 = @parametro2)
```

Adaptando esa lógica a tu caso concreto tendríamos:

```
where @id_cliente = 0 or i.Id_Cliente = @id_cliente
```

Comment: En SQL Server, la comparación es con un solo signo de igual

Comment: @LuisCazares demasiado c#, gracias por avisar

Comment: @bradbury9, En este caso solo traigo un valor que seria "@id_cliente"  y si es 0 este "@id_cliente"  que me lance todos los valores de la consulta  en cambio si esta "@id_cliente" es 2 por ejemplo que solo me traiga el registro 2 de mi tabla.

Comment: Cierto, pero como la propuesta que hago te sirve para un buscador tambien con un número N de parámetros por eso te la presento con dos parámetros. Siendo estrictos, en tu caso exacto sería `where @id_cliente = 0 or  i.Id_Cliente = @id_cliente`. Acabo de editar la respuesta para que quede mas claro

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvió, me ayudaste un montón.

Answer (score 0):

Si no sabes qué valor va a contener el ID_Cliente estamos ante una variable y como sabes este tipo de objeto viene asociado a un procedimiento almacenado o a una función. Para tu caso te recomiendo que explores las opciones de usar una función que retorne un valor tabla. SQL Server ha desarrollado múltiples sistemas para manejar este tipo de problemas desde su versión 2008 R2 y 2012 en adelante. Espero haberte ayudado. SALUDOS!

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE   i.Id_Cliente = CASE WHEN i.Id_Cliente = 0 
                                    THEN i.Id_Cliente   
                                    ELSE i.Id_Cliente = i.Id_Cliente
```

No pones parentesis y te sobra un igual
lo correcto seria:

```
WHERE   i.Id_Cliente = (CASE WHEN i.Id_Cliente = 0 
                                    THEN i.Id_Cliente   
                                    ELSE i.Id_Cliente)
```

estas indicando que la condicion es que idCliente sea igual a tu case

o

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN i.Id_Cliente = 0 
                                    THEN i.Id_Cliente   
                                    ELSE i.Id_Cliente) = i.Id_Cliente
```

Saludos, espero te sirva!

Comment: 1- El parentesis no es requisito, aunque facilita la legibilidad. 2- Tu condicion se comportaría mal con clientes cuyo Id sí sea cero. 3- OP emplea una variable (parametro) llamada `Id_cliente` que en tu respuesta no contemplas.